# Perform "shell:startup" in batch script

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to replicate <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then typing `shell:startup` as a Batch script.

[image: shellstartup]

Just putting this in a batch script doesn't work.

**How can I perform `shell:startup` in a batch script?**

Comment: `explorer shell:startup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either

```
explorer shell:startup
```

or

```
start "" shell:startup
```

As usual, if the *friendly* name  of a particular [Windows Shell Command](http://pc-addicts.com/pro-tip-windows-shell-commands/) contains a blank space, enclose it in double quotes, e.g. as follows:

```
start "" "shell:common startup"
```

or

```
explorer "shell:common startup"
```

Comment: `explorer shell:startup` works like a charm. And thanks for the explanation :) +1